# Handling org properties when include files

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I have a file a.org which contains

```
#+TITLE: a 
#+DATE: <2017-01-07 Sat>
* b.org
  #+INCLUDE: b.org
```

and b.org which contains

```
#+TITLE: b 
#+DATE: <2017-01-07 Sat>
* content in b
```

When I export a.org to html or latex, things like `#+TITLE` and `#+DATE` mess up.

[image]

Since I want to maintain each `b*.org` and a master `a.org` containing all the `b*.org` as subtrees.

So how can I tell org to ignore the properties in all the `b*.org` files and use the properties in `a.org` when exporting in `a.org`?

Comment: There is a small typo in your question: the file is called alternatively b.org and b1.org (in the code).

Comment: @Lgen Thanks for pointing out it. I forgot to update the image.

Comment: @erikstokes I think you are right: the proposed solution in your suggested link is simpler (and I think better) since the :minlevel 2 that I proposed in my answer is not required in this case.

Answer (score 1):

May be you could use `#+INCLUDE: b.org :minlevel 2  :lines "3-"`. This will skip the  first two lines in the file b.org and therefore will not include the unwanted title and date.

Comment: How can I detect the first heading position automatically? Since each file contains `C-c C-e #` options like latex, default, html, of all of them.